# Print Rails info-level log statements to stdout

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have rake tasks which call logger.info. In development, I'd like to see these messages on stdout as well. Is this possible without using my own log method which also calls puts?

Comment: Do you exclusivly want to see your log messages in stdout or do you want to see all messages from the environment log including yours?

Comment: I want to see all messages of a particular log level in stdout (in this case info)

Comment: Are you using a linux or windows operating system?

Comment: specify `config.log_level = :info` for your development environment of your application.

Comment: has my answer was helpful?

Answer (score 0):

Specify in thine development environment file **config/environments/development.rb** of thine application the following code line:

```
config.log_level = :info
```

There are `:debug`, `:info`, `:warn`, `:error`, `:fatal`, and `:unknown` log level that are consequently represent numbers of 0 to 5. Thou canst specify any of the level for the config variable.

Comment: That will stop my debug logs going to the log file. It won't make logs go to stdout.

Comment: I don't understand, fo you wan to log into a file, or to an stdout?

Comment: @Mispy I don't understand, fo you wan to log into a file, or to an stdout?